# Why is my application failing to create a bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have the following files:

UnitController.java

```
package com.fidolease.fidolease.controllers;

import com.fidolease.fidolease.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.fidolease.fidolease.models.Unit;
import com.fidolease.fidolease.repository.UnitRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class UnitController {
    @Autowired
    private UnitRepository unitRepository;

    @GetMapping("/units")
    public List<Unit> getAllUnits(){
        return unitRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/units/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Unit> getUnitById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long unitId)
        throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Unit unit = unitRepository.findById(unitId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Unit not found for this id :: " + unitId));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(unit);
    }
}
```

ErrorDetails.java

```
package com.fidolease.fidolease.exceptions;

import java.util.Date;

public class ErrorDetails {
    private Date timestamp;
    private String message;
    private String details;

    public ErrorDetails(Date timestamp, String message, String details) {
        super();
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.message = message;
        this.details = details;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }
}
```

GlobalExceptionHandler.java

```
package com.fidolease.fidolease.exceptions;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

import java.util.Date;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> resourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> globalExceptionHandler(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

ResourceNotFoundException.java

```
package com.fidolease.fidolease.exceptions;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends Exception{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ResourceNotFoundException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Unit.java

```
package com.fidolease.fidolease.models;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "units")
public class Unit {

    private long id;
    private String unit_heading;
    private int unit_type_id;
    private int number_of_bedroom;
    private double number_of_bathroom;
    private int number_of_balcony;
    private int leasing_info_id;
    private String date_of_posting;
    private String date_available_from;
    private int posted_by;
    private boolean is_active;
    private String unit_description;
    private int carpet_area;
    private String unit_number;
    private int unit_floor_number;
    private int parent_unit_id;

    public Unit(){ }

    public Unit(String unit_heading, int unit_type_id, int number_of_bedroom, double number_of_bathroom,
                int number_of_balcony, int leasing_info_id, String date_of_posting, String date_available_from,
                int posted_by, boolean is_active, String unit_description, int carpet_area, String unit_number,
                int unit_floor_number, int parent_unit_id) {
        this.unit_heading = unit_heading;
        this.unit_type_id = unit_type_id;
        this.number_of_bedroom = number_of_bedroom;
        this.number_of_bathroom = number_of_bathroom;
        this.number_of_balcony = number_of_balcony;
        this.leasing_info_id = leasing_info_id;
        this.date_of_posting = date_of_posting;
        this.date_available_from = date_available_from;
        this.posted_by = posted_by;
        this.is_active = is_active;
        this.unit_description = unit_description;
        this.carpet_area = carpet_area;
        this.unit_number = unit_number;
        this.unit_floor_number = unit_floor_number;
        this.parent_unit_id = parent_unit_id;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(long id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "unit_heading", nullable = false)
    public String getUnit_heading(){
        return this.unit_heading;
    }
    public void setUnit_heading(String unit_heading){
        this.unit_heading = unit_heading;
    }

    @Column(name = "unit_type_id", nullable = false)
    public int getUnit_type_id(){
        return this.unit_type_id;
    }
    public void setUnit_type_id(int unit_type_id){
        this.unit_type_id = unit_type_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "number_of_bedroom", nullable = false)
    public int getNumber_of_bedroom(){
        return this.number_of_bedroom;
    }
    public void setNumber_of_bedroom(int number_of_bedroom){
        this.number_of_bedroom = number_of_bedroom;
    }

    @Column(name = "number_of_bathroom", nullable = false)
    public double getNumber_of_bathroom(){
        return this.number_of_bathroom;
    }
    public void setNumber_of_bathroom(double number_of_bathroom){
        this.number_of_bathroom = number_of_bathroom;
    }

    @Column(name = "number_of_balcony", nullable = false)
    public int getNumber_of_balcony(){
        return this.number_of_balcony;
    }
    public void setNumber_of_balcony(int number_of_balcony){
        this.number_of_balcony = number_of_balcony;
    }

    @Column(name = "leasing_info_id", nullable = false)
    public int getLeasing_info_id(){
        return this.leasing_info_id;
    }
    public void setLeasing_info_id(int leasing_info_id){
        this.leasing_info_id = leasing_info_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "date_of_posting", nullable = false)
    public String getDate_of_posting(){
        return this.date_of_posting;
    }
    public void setDate_of_posting(String date_of_posting){
        this.date_of_posting = date_of_posting;
    }

    @Column(name = "date_available_from", nullable = false)
    public String getDate_available_from(){
        return this.date_available_from;
    }
    public void setDate_available_from(String date_available_from){
        this.date_available_from = date_available_from;
    }

    @Column(name = "posted_by", nullable = false)
    public int getPosted_by(){
        return this.posted_by;
    }
    public void setPosted_by(int posted_by){
        this.posted_by = posted_by;
    }

    @Column(name = "is_active", nullable = false)
    public boolean getIs_active(){
        return this.is_active;
    }
    public void setIs_active(boolean is_active){
        this.is_active = is_active;
    }

    @Column(name = "unit_description", nullable = false)
    public String getUnit_description(){
        return this.unit_description;
    }
    public void setUnit_description(String unit_description){
        this.unit_description = unit_description;
    }

    @Column(name = "carpet_area", nullable = false)
    public int getCarpet_area(){
        return this.carpet_area;
    }
    public void setCarpet_area(int carpet_area){
        this.carpet_area = carpet_area;
    }

    @Column(name = "unit_number", nullable = false)
    public String getUnit_number(){
        return this.unit_number;
    }
    public void setUnit_number(){
        this.unit_number = unit_number;
    }

    @Column(name = "unit_floor_number", nullable = false)
    public int getUnit_floor_number(){
        return this.unit_floor_number;
    }
    public void setUnit_floor_number(int unit_floor_number){
        this.unit_floor_number = unit_floor_number;
    }

    @Column(name = "parent_unit_id", nullable = false)
    public int getParent_unit_id(){
        return this.parent_unit_id;
    }
    public void setParent_unit_id(int parent_unit_id){
        this.parent_unit_id = parent_unit_id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Unit{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", unit_heading='" + unit_heading + '\'' +
                ", unit_type_id=" + unit_type_id +
                ", number_of_bedroom=" + number_of_bedroom +
                ", number_of_bathroom=" + number_of_bathroom +
                ", number_of_balcony=" + number_of_balcony +
                ", leasing_info_id=" + leasing_info_id +
                ", date_of_posting='" + date_of_posting + '\'' +
                ", date_available_from='" + date_available_from + '\'' +
                ", posted_by=" + posted_by +
                ", is_active=" + is_active +
                ", unit_description='" + unit_description + '\'' +
                ", carpet_area=" + carpet_area +
                ", unit_number='" + unit_number + '\'' +
                ", unit_floor_number=" + unit_floor_number +
                ", parent_unit_id=" + parent_unit_id +
                '}';
    }
}
```

UnitRepository.java

```
package com.fidolease.fidolease.repository;

import com.fidolease.fidolease.models.Unit;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UnitRepository extends JpaRepository<Unit, Long> {

}
```

FidoLeaseApplication.java

```
package com.fidolease.fidolease;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FidoleaseApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FidoleaseApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I run the application, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'unitRepository' defined in com.fidolease.fidolease.repository.UnitRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
```

When I searched around, it seemed as if the error might occur if I don't have JPA in my pom file but after searching it, I have the following:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here or maybe a reference to some documentation that may explain my issue? Thank you all for your time and if there is anything I can do to clarify, please let me know.

EDIT: The following is my properties file:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://digitaloceanservername:theport/mydbname
spring.datasource.username=myusername
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
```

Edit 2: Adding the full strack trac -> https://pastebin.com/RskBMJjL

Comment: `Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;` should be the key in your problem. Where and how do you configure Hibernate?

Comment: Apologies if this is not a smart question as I am still learning, but are you asking how I have it installed in my maven file?

Comment: Question is OK, and you don't have to apologize. I'm just asking how is your Hibernate Configured? you should have some properties file (if you let SpringBoot to configure it), or maybe hibernate.cfg.xml, or somewhere in your Java code, you should be configuring it.. `SessionFactory` is a backbone of entire Hibernate, so if that won't work, your ORM tool won't work.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri thank you for your time. So I have a properties named application.properties which has my DB settings in it. I have added that to my post. That is the only manual properties I have set though.

Comment: So you don't have any class annotated with `@Configuration` or something like that?

Comment: Please include full stack trace.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri No I do not. I'll dig into that though thank you so much. I tried adding the stack trace but it was too large for the post so I edited in a url with a pastebin that is available here https://pastebin.com/RskBMJjL

Comment: At least, try to add the bottom lines (as much as you can, start from bottom).

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I can't believe I just wasted your time like this and I am sorry. I read the bottom line as I was going to copy it for you and it clearly stated that I forget to create a setter method for one of my variables. I did that, and the server started right up. Thank you so much for your time and I will delete this post.

Comment: Relax, all is OK. Good luck. Next time, just pay attention to logs and stack trace. They, most likely, will tell you what's the problem.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri thank you

Comment: Using a code generator such as [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) can help clean up a lot of these boilerplate code and prevent errors such as these.

Comment: @shinjw awesome! Thank you.. just started digging into it. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in your setter method for unit_number, it is not taking a parameter. It should be:

```
public void setUnit_number(String unit_number){
    this.unit_number = unit_number;
}
```